# Can I use Enumerations as type parameters in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'd like to use an Enumeration as a type parameter by the compiler is giving me grief.

```
object VehicleClass extends Enumeration {
  type VehicleClass = Value
  val Land, Air, Sea = Value
}
import VehicleClass._

trait Vehicle[K <: VehicleClass] { val kind: K }
case class Car(passengers: Int) extends Vehicle[Land] { val kind: Land }
```

Compiler complains:

```
[error] /Users/me/test/scala/co.blocke.scalajack/json/test.misc/Greg.scala:18: not found: type Land
[error] case class Car(passengers: Int) extends Vehicle[Land] { val kind: Land }
[error]                                                 ^
[error] /Users/me/test/scala/co.blocke.scalajack/json/test.misc/Greg.scala:18: not found: type Land
[error] case class Car(passengers: Int) extends Vehicle[Land] { val kind: Land }
[error]                                                                   ^
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Why do you need an Enumeration? Maybe you can achieve the same result with a sealed trait VehicleClass and Land, Air and Sea as case classes that extend the trait

Comment: As Alexey says you can get this to work with Enumerations, but this would be more straight forward with an ADT as Josep points out.  I never use scala.Enumeration, this link might help you understand more http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/09/03/enumerations.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write

```
case class Car(passengers: Int) extends Vehicle[Land.type] { 
  val kind: Land.type = Land 
}
```

`Land.type` is the *singleton type* of `Land`, i.e. the type whose only value is `Land` (not including `null`).

Answer (score 1):

Alexey has provided the correct answer for using `scala.Enumeration`

I would address this problem using an ADT instead of enumerations which I regard as deprecated. (See http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/09/03/enumerations.html)

Here is the solution using ADTs

```
// Using an abstract class makes accessing things in VehicleClass companion 
// object nicer
sealed abstract class VehicleClass

case object Land extends VehicleClass
case object Air extends VehicleClass
case object Sea extends VehicleClass

trait Vehicle[K <: VehicleClass] { val kind: K }
case class Car(passengers: Int) extends Vehicle[Land.type] { val kind = Land }
```

I would simplify this code somewhat, as generally do not see the requirement to make the `trait Vehicle` generic.  What extra safety does this add to your code?  I would generally simplify the trait to

```
trait Vehicle { val kind: VehicleClass }
```

(The only reason I can see to make `Vehicle` generic would be to define type class instances for `Vehicle[Land]` instead of for all of the types of `Vehicle[Land]`, but then `Vehicle` would probably need more members.)